# Making GeoServer use Windows ADP to access SQL database

Tags: geoserver, wms, sql-server, windows

I will start this by saying i'm completely out of my depths with this, but alas, I will try anyways.

I'm trying to create a WMS of the spatial layers in our project for our tablets to use when we are out GPS'ing.

I did some searching online and came across GeoServer, which I have running locally on my machine.
I have it looking at a folder containing a bunch of our shapefiles and it works, displaying a WMS in QGIS as expected.

The issues I'm having is that I want it to connect to our SQL database and read the live data (our shapefiles are produced by a nightly FME script so they are a day behind) but I can't access the database via GeoServer. I'm in a corporate setting so there are a bunch of security settings and we need to use ADP to access our SQL Database but I'm not sure how to make GeoServer use ADP so it can get access to the SQL Server.

Is this possible? Am I going about this the right way?

It may not be an access issue but from the error message and what IT has said it's looking like an access issue.

This is what I'm entering into GeoServer to connect to the database and the error produced

[image]
[image]